# The view ___ didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a scheduling app where patients can register for appointments. When I submit the form for a new appointment, I get the value error.

views.py

```
def patient_portal(request):
    appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(patient=request.user.patient.pid)
    data_input = request.GET.get('date')
    selected_date = Appointment.objects.filter(date = data_input).values_list('timeslot', flat=True)
    available_appointments = [(value, time) for value, time in Appointment.TIMESLOT_LIST if value not in selected_date]
    doctor =  Patient.objects.get(doctor=request.user.patient.doctor).doctor
    print(doctor)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(initial={'doctor': doctor,'patient': request.user.patient}, instance=request.user.patient)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('../home/')
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm(initial={'doctor': doctor,'patient': request.user.patient}, instance=request.user.patient)
        return render(request, 'scheduling/patient.html', {"form" : form, "appointments" : appointments, "available_appointments" : available_appointments, "data_input": data_input, "doctor": doctor})
```

patient.html:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="timeslot" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form|crispy }}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

forms.py:

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('doctor','patient','date','timeslot')
```

Comment: `doctor =  Patient.objects.get(doctor=request.user.patient.doctor).doctor` looks more complicated than it needs to be. Wouldn’t `doctor = request.user.patient.doctor` work?

Answer (score 3):

Your view must always return an HTTP response. At the moment, your code doesn't handle the case when `request.method == 'POST'`, but the form is invalid.

You can fix your code by de-indenting the final `return` statement, to move it outside of the else block:

```
def patient_portal(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(initial={'doctor': doctor,'patient': request.user.patient}, instance=request.user.patient)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('../home/')
    else:
        form = AppointmentForm(initial={'doctor': doctor,'patient': request.user.patient}, instance=request.user.patient)
    return render(request, 'scheduling/patient.html', {"form" : form, "appointments" : appointments, "available_appointments" : available_appointments, "data_input": data_input, "doctor": doctor})
```

Comment: How can I troubleshoot the form error? I looked at this link but still couldn't get the error message to display: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, so I can't help you with that here. You have `{{ form|crispy }}` in the template, so the rendered template should display any form errors. You could also try adding `print(form.errors)` to your view and look for the output in the console where `runserver` is running.

Comment: Yeah I tried using `print(form.errors)` and it prints a blank line.

Comment: You haven’t bound your form to any data. For pos requests you should have `form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)`.

Comment: Your `AppointmentForm` has `model = Appointment`, so `instance=request.user.patient` doesn’t make sense because it’s the wrong model. You only need to provide `instance` when you are updating an existing appointment. If you are creating a new appointment, then you shouldn’t specify `instance`.